# How to pack a rails application into an exe file to distrubute it with tar2rubyscript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, distribute

I was following this How-To on Distributing Rails Applications

http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/distributingrubyapplications/rails.html

but by the time i do

`$ ruby tar2rubyscript.rb desktopApp/`

the output is

`#=> tar2rubyscript.rb doesn't contain an init.rb .`

so i followed this steps here:

https://github.com/ryanbooker/tar2rubyscript

and nope... it's still not working.

any help on this or any alternative to tar2rubyscript?

Thank you all.